Regex match entire words only and words only + x amount of characters
I want a regex string, that finds words on X amount of characters, but it can't be the same letters many times.
So let's say i use the string: /^w{1,10}$/
It will find all words with 1 to 10 characters.
But it will also find VVVVVVVVVV (Because there are 10 characters)
Is it possible to make a string that only finds real words, or not get hits on word with many of the same characters

Please clarify your question and add some example, expected result

No, you can't. Real words are not defined by expressions nor patterns. Regular Expression is not the right tool for that.

You may use some function expression like:
var txt = 'I want a regex string, that finds words on X amount of characters, but it can't be the same letters many times.'; txt.split(/\s/gi).filter(x => (x.length > 0 && x.length<=10));

Please explain in details

But is it not possible to make a regex that dosent allow X amout of letters in a word.
So a word like : hello is fine
But if it says lets say: vvvvvv i dont want a hit, or Heello.
